# High latency, connection and queue depth in Airflow postgres backend

Tags: postgresql, airflow

We are running airflow with Postgres(in RDS) as metadata DB and as a result backend and Redis as a Celery backend. Over the weekend the read/write latency and subsequently the number of connections and queue depth increased that

- Number of tasks failed with Timeout
- All of the airflow slowed down

[image: Write latency]

Eventually modifying the DB instance to a larger instance resolved the issue, however not sure what was the root cause of this issue is not obvious yet.

Have someone else faced this issue and have a solution?

```
Airflow: 1.10.5
Postgres: 9.6.15
```